# SQL query error in application, but works in Visual Studio Server Explorer

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following SQL statement in vb.net :

```vb
Try
    konneksie.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "With cte As ( " &
           " Select Case SkedTonKultKlasGereed, " &
           " Res = sum(SkedSkatting) over (partition by skedkult, skedslaagB, skedklas) " &
           " From Skedulering) " &
           " Update cte Set SkedTonKultKlasGereed = res"

    COMMAND = New SqlCommand(Query, konneksie)
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    MessageBox.Show("Ton per kultivar en klas wat aan suiker parsreels voldoen bepaal ")
    konneksie.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
End Try
konneksie.Close()
```

However when I run my application I get an error :

> Incorrect syntax near ",".

When I run the query outside my application (in Visual Studio Server Explorer) it works.

What am I missing ?

Comment: The `Case` infront of `SkedTonKultKlasGereed` is not required in your scenario

Comment: Thank you Arulkumar. Yes that was it.

Comment: @Arulkumar Make you comment as answer

Comment: @JohnyL Added as answer.

Comment: @KinchitDalwani What for?

Answer (score 1):

Your query contains the syntax error.

`Case` in front of the `SkedTonKultKlasGereed` in the `SELECT` is not required in your given query. Removing the `Case` will fix your error.

Comment: If it solves your problem, can you please consider for [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)